# post-css dynamic variable from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, postcss

I have a question, it is possible to set dynamic variable or change variable from JS in post-css?
I have react component and inside css3 animation, I want set dynamic delay for each animation individually for each component.

I found similar solution, that I can pass property and read it from css for example JS code:

```
<div className={style.component} delay={5}>
```

and I can read it in CSS but only like if statement:

```
&[delay="5"] {
 animation: show 0.1s linear forwards 5s;
```

}

and it works!
but I want something like:

```
animation: show 0.1s linear forwards [delay]s; //dynamic delay value here
```

it is possible?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the dynamic value **'5'** as a prop like this:

```
const App = (props) => {

      return (

        <div className={style.component} style={{animation: "show 0.1s linear forwards " + (props.delayStyle + 's')}}>
            // Div Content Here
        </div>

      )

};

ReactDOM.render(<App delayStyle='5' />, document.getElementById('someDiv'));
```

---

**CodePen:** https://codepen.io/andrewl64/pen/dKzzaJ

Comment: Hello, yeah of course I know this solution, but it is very ugly and not usable when I have for loop like this:

`@for $i from 1 to 7 {
      & :nth-child($i) {
        animation: show 0.1s linear forwards calc($i * 0.05)s;
      }
    }`

I just thought that this can be very easy do in post-css